# Internet Explorer : Float and Clear Issues

Tags: html, css

So I am having an issue in IE, but not FireFox or Chrome. The issue is my floats and clears are not being consistant.

Please take a look at my Live Page Examples in IE and any other Browser.

http://newsite.702wedding.com/elvis-wedding-las-vegas.asp

I was considering putting the right elements in a div called float right and the rest in a div called float left, but seems to not work in IE.

I think I may be overlooking something simple. >.<

Thanks for your Help.
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow:hidden;` on the container of the floats.  That should clear.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the elements containing the floats have `zoom:1` or a hasLayout trigger like `width` specified, that should make the containers clear them.